# Mutators not always called in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

I use a Mutator in my user object to format it:

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($avatar){
    if (is_null($avatar) ||strlen($avatar)==0){
        $avatar = 'avatar.png';
    }

    // If avatar comes from facebook, it comes with http://
    if (!str_contains($avatar, 'http')){

        //dd($avatar); // WHen I enable it, it never stop :(

        $avatar = Config::get('constants.AVATAR_PATH').$avatar;

    }else{

        //dd($avatar); // When I enable it, it stop when FB url pic
    }


    return $avatar;
}
```

Thing is code call my mutator when I call it from

```
 Auth::getUser()->avatar;
```

But it is not called when I use

```
$user = User::where("email", "=","foo@bar.com")->first();
$user->avatar;
```

When I do var_dump in my view, I have:

```
object(stdClass)#365 (20) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(4) "juju" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "may" ["lastname"]=> string(1) "1" ["email"]=> string(13) "juju@juju.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$5LEhHJhQdbBw9t4IW7p1M./a1x/ADWRf5D2fGj2x9OH1LQH0Qj0TG" ["gradeId"]=> int(1) ["countryId"]=> int(36) ["roleId"]=> int(3) ["avatar"]=> NULL ["verified"]=> int(1) ["token"]=> string(30) "lKCLYZXaktRVI9j3zClUHLncxMBbXt" ["provider"]=> string(4) "seed" ["provider_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["remember_token"]=> string(60) "53Dl2ak2Nony1FJ1SZajOb1sLiFyrjAz9tcJg2InJBUbbMAd98blPRwRDari" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-11-26 01:18:14" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2015-11-26 17:55:27" ["grade"]=> string(9) "Sin grado" ["country"]=> string(9) "Australia" ["flag"]=> string(6) "AU.png" }
```

EDIT:

I guess , my initial query is a JOIN, so it doesn't fetch in a User object :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('countries', 'users.countryId', '=', 'countries.id')
        ->leftJoin('grade', 'users.gradeId', '=', 'grade.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'grade.name as grade', 'countries.name as country', 'countries.flag')
        ->get();
```

But I still doesn't know how to fix it properly....

Comment: What you're using is an **accessor** used to get data (also known as a getter method), **mutators** are used to set data (also known as setter methods). That being said, your code looks perfectly fine so it should work just fine. The idea is that accessors are only called when getting that property. So if you `var_dump($user)` that will give you the data fetched from the database, the accessor will only apply that logic if you did `var_dump($user->avatar)`.

Comment: I guess I found something, my initial query is a JOIN, so it doesn't fetch in a User object : I updated my question

Comment: You're using the Query Builder to fetch the results, which will return a collection of plain objects. The accessor is defined on the model, so you need to build the query using the model, so it will return model objects. It should be: `$users = \App\User::select('users.*', 'grade.name as grade', 'countries.name as country', 'countries.flag')->leftJoin('countries', 'users.countryId', '=', 'countries.id')->leftJoin('grade', 'users.gradeId', '=', 'grade.id')->get();`.

Comment: yes, it did the trick! Please put it as answer! Tx for your help!

Comment: Posted it as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries%60) to fetch the results, which will return a collection of plain objects. The accessor is defined on the model, so you need to build the query using the model as the starting point, in order for it to return model instances. It should be:

```php
$users = \App\User::select('users.*', 'grade.name as grade', 'countries.name as country', 'countries.flag')
                  ->leftJoin('countries', 'users.countryId', '=', 'countries.id')
                  ->leftJoin('grade', 'users.gradeId', '=', 'grade.id')
                  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Eloquent wrong.

If you want to get a single user with that email your have to use

```
$user = User::where("email", "=","foo@bar.com")->first();
```

If there could be more users, then you can get them all with

```
$user = User::where("email", "=","foo@bar.com")->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it bad, but I use it as you say... I will correct my question